# On what quantity the Dividend is given in India?

Tags: india, dividends, nse-india, stock-dividend

I do have stocks (purchased) in a Script in India.
The stock declared announced the Dividend on 20 May 2015, and I purchased the equity recently (few days back), but the Stock equity's Effective
Date is 30 August.

So I wanted to know whether I will get the dividend or not? If yes then how much?

Update:

Lets take an example: 
Here is the Dividends data provided by MRF
http://www.moneycontrol.com/company-facts/mrf/dividends/MRF#MRF

Where the latest dividend was **Announced** on 27-07-15 and **Effective Date** is 06-08-15. So My question is if I purchased the shares on 03-08-15 then will I get the dividend?

Comment: What do you mean by "Stock equity's Effective Date is 30 August."? And you say "Dividend on 20 May 2015" is this the date when announcement was made or the record date?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: US folks please note that the dates are in dd-mm-yy format and not the mm-dd-yy format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So My question is if I purchased the shares on 03-08-15 then will I get the dividend?

Yes if you purchase on 3-Aug, the shares will actually get credited to your account on 5-Aug and hence you will hold the shares on 6-Aug, the record date.

Answer (score 0):

In India, the amount of dividend you get is based on the face value of the stock. If the stock's face value is Rs. 10 and the company announced a dividend of 20%, you will receive Rs.2 per share.To see whether you qualify to receive a dividend, see the ex-dividend date of the company. If you purchased shares before that date, you will receive the dividend, else you will not